# Custom defined sideways floats don't centre horizontally

Tags: floats, rotating

I have defined a custom floating environment `scheme` with the `rotfloat` package, which also defines the corresponding `sidewaysscheme*` environment.
However, when I use this environment in a two-column document class, the resulting float is not horizontally centred, as the following MWE demonstrates:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\newfloat{scheme}{tbp}{lop}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysscheme*}
    Test
    \caption{Test}
\end{sidewaysscheme*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Non-centred sidewaysscheme*]

The text and caption are clearly to the right of the correctly centred page number. Changing `sidewaysscheme*` into `sidewaysfigure*` *does* yield a well-centred floating environment. Since the latter is defined by `rotating` by default, I suspect that somehow `rotfloat` defines the custom float slightly differently, but I don't know why/how.

I would very much like to know why custom-defined floats don't centre horizontally and how to fix this.

Comment: Rotfloat isn't the only or best package you can use.  Rotating or even \rotatebox from graphicx and a minipage will work.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know why `rotfloat` defines the new `sidewaysscheme*` to behave differently than `sidewaysfigure*`, but redefining the former to behave like the latter seems to have the desired effect:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{sidewaysscheme*}{\@rotdblfloat{scheme}}{\end@rotdblfloat}
\makeatother
```